# Why should I replace null literal with null object?

Tags: java, refactoring

Theres a method we are using and no changes can be done to it.

```
void existingMethod(String p1, String p2){
    if(p1==null)
        p1 = makeP1();
    //do work
}
```

While I called the method from my code,

```
existingMethod(null, "dfdfdf");
```

I got a review comment to create `String NULL_STRING = null`, and use that variable instead of `null` literal in my code. How do you justify that?

Edit: Is it meant for sole purpose of readability? Then I have similar methods that take `Long amount,` and for some functions, we are passing `null`. How does it makes sense to do same with `NULL_AMOUNT`?

Comment: That is honestly a bullshit review comment.

Comment: This seems to go against maintainability. It would be the same as making a global variable for the character `'A'`. What is that variable changes? Even if it doesn't, now the developer has to look at the use and the variable declaration instead of just looking at the use. Renaming `null` is dumb.

Comment: I don't justify it; I think the suggestion is dumb.  It's possible that there is something requiring that in the project's style guidelines, however.  This is not the place for a discussion of code style, however.  If you want that, then I think it would be on-topic over at [Software Engineering SE](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Can we move it?

Comment: @xploreraj, Software Engineering is not among the automatic migration targets for SO.  If you want to move the question, then delete it from here, and ask it as a new question over there.  Inasmuch as you seem to be getting answers here anyway, however, that may not be worth the trouble.

Comment: In general including the value in the variable name is very bad practice - the variable name should reflect its purpose / behaviour / function. Having a `final int ONE = 1;` is useless, having a `final int DEFAULT_GRID_SIZE = 1;` is reasonable. What if the *value* changes? Now the default is 2, will you rename the variable? Or will you now use a variable named ONE which has the value 2?

Comment: @luk2302 True. What about the amount variable then I mentioned in last?

Comment: You should stop passing null around everywhere. Especially for boxed types that is quickly gonna run into problems. Define a second method with the same name which does not have an `amount` parameter and which delegates to calling the previous method with `0` as the default amount, for the `0` you might define a `final Long DEFAULT_AMOUNT = 0L;`

Answer (score 2):

That's a question about code style. I would not recommend to do it, but the reasoning might be extensibility.

Imagine someone introduces a new overload of that method:

```
void existingMethod(OtherClass p1, String p2) {
   ...
}
```

Now `existingMethod(null, "dfdfdf");` leads to a compilation error whereas `existingMethod(NULL_STRING, "dfdfdf");` does not.

Comment: This makes sense.

Comment: If you would have a solid test suite that should be easily discoverable anyway. No need to clutter the code.

Comment: On the other hand, calling it as `existingMethod((String) null, "dfdfdf")` serves the same purpose, and is clearer (to me).

Comment: @luk2302 As I said, I would not recommend it. But how a test suite catches a compilation error is a mystery to me.

Comment: It does not catch the compilation error, but it catches whatever unexpected behaviour would arise from silently adding a new overloaded method.

Comment: Ridiculous.  Refactor it *when* there's an overload, not before.

Comment: which comes on top of other in terms of good refactoring vision and industry practice - Axel's answer or John16384's comment? Both seem to be valid to me. But also the fact we can't always keep the future change possibilities while writing code.

Answer (score 1):

There are always two perspectives to such questions:

1. They are about "style"; and style always depends on what **your** team agrees the standards to follow are.
2. There are also "general" best practices that affect certain aspects (such as readability).

In other words: when everybody in your team would expect that some TYPED_NULL_CONST is used instead of null, then maybe that would be the way to go.

But on the other hand, most people outside of your team would find this policy to be extremely awkward.

In that sense: talk to the person who gave that review comment, and see where it is coming from; and what the thinking behind is. Then deal with it.

And for the record: our team prefers methods that neither take null, nor return null.

Comment: Not a team standard.

Comment: Then do what you think makes sense here ;-)

Comment: Well, that is a social problem; and on a completely different level. But one sentence there: if rejecting a review comment; or asking to discuss it turns into a "big conflict" situation, then you should address **that** part. In that case, the technical issues are **not** the important thing right now.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `existingMethod` is questionable, as it expects `null` values. Technically - well, it works.

But I'd provide at least an overloaded method like

```
void existingMethod(String p2) {
    existingMethod(null, p2)
}
```

In general - so called null objects are good practice. It's a way to avoid a lot of NPE right away. But I agree with the commentators that declaring a constant to send a real `null` is ... bullshit.

Comment: Yup.  That's what I also did while writing new methods. This is about existing method that I shouldn't touch.

Answer (score 1):

To get a bit pedantic, you are not being asked to use a Null Object. As @GhostCat said you have a Typed Null Constant. The [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) uses an actual object of whatever type, that does nothing when methods are called on it. It can be passed instead of null. I don't see much value in the Typed Null Constant myself.